Mismatch found for java and native libraries java build version 6.1.0.20180926230239.GA, native build version 6.1.0.20171109191718.GA
I am trying to read a CSV file for using Spark Scala API as part of prepping data.
While running the same file I am getting below issue.
2024-09-12 11:26:46,0484 ERROR JniCommon fc/jni_MapRClient.cc:795 Thread: 12962582528 Mismatch found for java and native libraries java build version 6.1.0.20180926230239.GA, native build version 6.1.0.20171109191718.GA java patch vserion $Id: mapr-version: 6.1.0.20180926230239.GA 9008f798f53897bea861, native patch version $Id: mapr-version: 6.1.0.20171109191718.GA 2227eb16eb6dc79ffe87
2024-09-12 11:26:46,0484 ERROR JniCommon fc/jni_MapRClient.cc:812 Thread: 12962582528 Client initialization failed.


Could not create FileClient
java.io.IOException: Could not create FileClient

System - MacOS and Java 8 as Compiler.
Below is code used.
  def readDataCSV(): DataFrame = {
    var filePath = "/user/library/com/src/test/spark-test/param.csv"

    spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("delimiter", ",").load(filePath)
  }

